What state is a particle in before it passes through any Stern-Gerlach devices?
Say we fire some large number N of silver atoms out of a furnace and through a Stern-Gerlach device, which is oriented at some arbitrary angle x. If I understand correctly, then regardless of what x is, about N/2 of those silver atoms will be deflected "up" and about N/2 will be deflected "down" (i.e., a 50/50 split). If we place another Stern-Gerlach device in the path of the "up" spinning atoms, and orient it at exactly angle x again, then none of the atoms will change from "up" to "down": all N/2 will be deflected "up" once again. However, if we place a third Stern-Gerlach device in the path of those N/2 atoms, and we orient the device to a new angle y, which is perpendicular to x, then when the x-measured atoms come through, they will split yet again, with about N/4 going "up" (relative to y) and about N/4 going "down". And if we then place in the path of the y-up atoms yet another Stern-Gerlach device oriented at angle x, it will again split into about N/8 "up" and N/8 "down".

The point being, as Friebe, Kuhlmann, et. al. write in The Philosophy of Quantum Physics (2018): "The measurement of y clearly destroys the results of the previous x measurement, so that a further measurement of x is not a repetition of its first measurement." (p. 9) Nevertheless,

every particle which has been shown to have its spin up (or its spin down) in a previous measurement must show with certainty the same result in a later measurement, independently of how much time has elapsed between the two measurements as long as no external influences (such as magnetic fields) perturb the particles. One says that spin measurements are repeatable. (p. 7)

My question is this: what state were the silver atoms in before they passed through the first Stern-Gerlach device?
If at the beginning I had said, "Say some large number N of silver atoms, which have already passed through an x-oriented Stern-Gerlach device, were then to pass through another x-oriented Stern-Gerlach device?" then we would have to say that all N of those silver atoms will pass through the second device. But as I understand it, when the silver atoms are first produced and shot out of the furnace, the first Stern-Gerlach device is guaranteed to split them 50/50, regardless of its particular orientation (our choice of x was arbitrary). This implies that, before passing through that first Stern-Gerlach device, the silver atoms are in some kind of special, neutral state with regard to Stern-Gerlach devices. It is as though they are in a superposition, not only of states, but of operators themselves, if that makes any sense.
(In my mind, this question is related to a previous question of mine, Where does the quantum state come from, prior to the application of operators? I understand my phrasing of the question there was very confusing and betrayed me as an amateur; nevertheless, the underlying question I was trying to express there is closely related to my question here. I want to know what the "initial state" of a quantum particle is, before any measurement is performed on it. What does it "look like" in its vector space? And how is this determined? I know the process is apparently called "quantum state tomography", but from what I've read, it still seems to presuppose an initial measurement upon the "raw" quantum state. And it is precisely that "raw" state that I am interested in--or whether there even is such a thing!)

So the initial state is not a pure state. It's an unpolarized mixed state, which is described by a density matrix:
$$ \rho = \frac 1 2
\Big(\chi_+^{\dagger}\chi_+ +
\chi_-^{\dagger}\chi_-\Big)$$
$$
\rho =\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac 1 2 & 0 \\
0 & \frac 1 2
\end{array}
\right]
$$
where $\chi_{\pm}$ are the usual column vectors.
Note that $\rho$ is isotropic: it is invariant under rotations of $\chi_{\pm}$, so the definition of a $z$-axis direction is truly arbitrary.
The problem, as stated, adds the arbitrary direction into the $x$ definition, but I see that as unnecessary (though I see why they did it). It's unnecessary, because $z$ is arbitrary. We can do this on the ISS so there is no natural up/down direction to bias us.
Hence: you can just say "a SG device that measures along the $z$-axis" since the $z$-axus is arbitrary--and it's the standard axis for math.
What you get then is an entanglement of position and spin.
I don't want to get into a LaTex mess, so I'll define my possible spatial wave functions (loosely) as:
$$\psi_{\pm} = \delta(z_{\pm}/2) $$
ignoring $x, y, t$ dependence (here you can define a continuous beam or a wave packet--details.) What that describes is an upper beam and lower beam (but we're on the ISS, so up/down is whatever you want it to be).
You then have a total space $\otimes$ spin wave function like:
$$ \Psi(z) = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}
\Big(
\psi_+(z)\chi_+ + \psi_-(z)\chi_- 
\Big)
$$
which can not be written as a simple product of space and spin:
$$\psi(z)\chi $$
hence, the entanglement.
From here, if you put the upper beam into another SG device, you just forget the lower part of the wave function and star-over with a pure spin-up ($z$-wise) beam, so for instance, if it is oriented in the $x$ direction, you get a new wave-function coming out:
$$ \Psi = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}\Big(
\psi_+(x)\chi_+^{(x)} + \psi_-(x)\chi_-^{(x)}\Big)$$
etc, etc.
Note: if you start with $N$ particles, you have to restart the second SG device with $N/2$. This is somewhat playing "fast and loose".
When I took General Relativity in grad-school, the professor, Kip Thorne said, "everyone should compute the Riemann curvature tensor of a sphere, once".
I feel the same way about the Stern-Gerlach experiment: everyone should work out the arbitrary 3 device set-up with density matrices, once. Which is why I am only posting the short-cut version here today.

My understanding is that particles are first subjected to a strong magnetic field, oriented along the $\hat z$ axis, say, (or a direction orthogonal to the subsequence measurement basis) so that the initial state is $|\uparrow_z\rangle$ in the $\hat z$ measurement basis.  In the $\hat x$ measurement basis, this state would be $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|\uparrow_x\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle_x)$, and hence the subsequent magnetic field gradient splits the beam into up and down components.  Note that it isn't until the particles irreversibly interact with a screen that a "measurement" can take place (by observing the state of the screen): before then, their wave function is merely "filtered" (or "stratified".)
Without the strong external field to initialize spins along a definite axis, the spins of particles would be aligned randomly.  In aggregate, the density matrix describing statistical properties of the ensemble would be 'completely mixed', but individual particles would still presumably occupy pure single particle states.  Since the peaks that appear in the Stern-Gerlach experiment are caused by the discreteness of spin (and not coherence effects), the beam could still be split as before into distinct channels.  With a completely mixed state, however, the interference characteristics from recombining distinct sectors of the beam in various ways would differ from those for a pure state (especially w.r.t. spin components): even if each individual particle occupies a coherent wave function, linearity of the Schroedinger equation implies that the aggregate density matrix of the ensemble is determined by the time evolution of the initial density matrix (whose spin components are completely mixed.)  In order to observe any interference effects at all, you would need particles prepared with a definite (or at least "semi-coherent") spatial wave function (and the random spin would only obscure/occlude/conflate otherwise-visible spatial interference patterns from each spin-sector.)

I also recall that the original experiment utilized spin-polarized incoming electron.  But I wonder whether a uniform mixed state of all spin orientations would also work?
